# How to avoid data duplicate when navigate screen?

Tags: react-native, react-redux, react-navigation

My situation is i have two `FlatList` component (A and B).

A is my first screen. I use `react-navigation` to navigate A to B , B will show back arrow on headerLeft. When i click the arrow it will back to A . But the FlatList data is still show B even it is really in A...

My data is from fetch API by `react-redux`, i think the problem is come from `react-redux`. Because i test a simple test without `react-redux`. The problem is gone.

I want to use react-redux create my project. I try to use `shouldComponentUpdate` like

```
shouldComponentUpdate = (nextProps, nextState) => {
    if (nextProps.movieList === this.props.movieList) {
      return false;
    }
    return true;
  };
```

It is still can't fix my problem when `goBack()` to another component

I console.log it try to find what is going on with my props data.
When i navigate to B from A. My console.log will show like this, i find A component will be rendered... [image]

Then i click the back arrow on headerLeft to A. The screen is A but the data is still B add my console.log is empty at the same time.

I can't figure it out. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Here is my A component file (B is similar with A):

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { 
  View, FlatList, Dimensions, 
  TouchableOpacity, Image,
  ActivityIndicator, Alert, Platform
} from 'react-native';
import { Icon } from 'react-native-elements';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { fetchMainMovieList } from '../actions';

const { width, height } = Dimensions.get('window');
const equalWidth = (width / 2);

class MainActivity extends Component {
  static navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => ({
    title: 'MainActivity',
    headerLeft: 
      <TouchableOpacity style={{ marginLeft: 10 }} onPress={() => navigation.navigate('DrawerOpen')} >
        <Icon name='menu' />
      </TouchableOpacity>
  });

  componentWillMount() {
    this.props.fetchMainMovieList();
  }

  renderItem({ item }) {
    return (
      <View>
        <Image 
          source={{ uri: item.photoHref }} 
          style={{ height: 220, width: equalWidth }} 
          resizeMode="cover" 
        />
      </View>
    );
  }

  render() {
    const movieData = this.props.movieList.movie;
    console.log('A component this.props=>');
    console.log(this.props);
    if (movieData === []) {
      return (
        <View style={styles.loadingStyle}>
          <ActivityIndicator />
        </View>
      );
    }
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
        <FlatList
          data={movieData}
          renderItem={this.renderItem} 
          numColumns={2}
          horizontal={false}
          keyExtractor={(item, index) => index} 
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = {
  loadingStyle: {
    flex: 1, 
    flexDirection: 'column', 
    justifyContent: 'center', 
    alignItems: 'center'
  }
};

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  const movieList = state.movieList;

  return { movieList };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { fetchMainMovieList })(MainActivity);
```

Here is my B component file:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { 
  View, FlatList, Dimensions, 
  Image, ActivityIndicator, Text
} from 'react-native';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { fetchThisWeek } from '../actions';

const { width, height } = Dimensions.get('window');
const equalWidth = (width / 2);

class ThisWeek extends Component {
  static navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => ({
    title: 'ThisWeek',
  });

  componentWillMount() {
    this.props.fetchThisWeek();
  }

  renderItem({ item }) {
    return (
      <View>
        <Image 
          source={{ uri: item.photoHref }} 
          style={{ height: 500, width: '100%' }} 
          resizeMode="cover" 
        />
      </View>
    );
  }

  render() {
    const movieData = this.props.movieList.movie;
    console.log('B component this.props=>');
    console.log(this.props);
    if (movieData === []) {
      return (
        <View style={styles.loadingStyle}>
          <ActivityIndicator />
        </View>
      );
    }
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
        <FlatList
          data={movieData}
          renderItem={this.renderItem} 
          numColumns={1}
          horizontal={false}
          keyExtractor={(item, index) => index} 
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = {
  loadingStyle: {
    flex: 1, 
    flexDirection: 'column', 
    justifyContent: 'center', 
    alignItems: 'center'
  }
};

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  const movieList = state.movieList;

  return { movieList };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { fetchThisWeek })(ThisWeek);
```

Here is my MyListReducer.js:

```
import { 
  MOVIELIST_MAINACTIVITY,
  MOVIELIST_THISWEEK,
  MOVIELIST_THEATER
} from '../actions/types';

const INITIAL_STATE = {};

export default (state = INITIAL_STATE, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {   
    case MOVIELIST_MAINACTIVITY:
      return action.payload;

    case MOVIELIST_THISWEEK:
      return action.payload;

    case MOVIELIST_THEATER:
      console.log(action.payload);
      return action.payload;

    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

Comment: Are you using the same class for component B?

Comment: No, component B is another class component. I have post my B component file on my question.

Comment: Are the functions 
this.props.fetchMainMovieList(); 
this.props.fetchThisWeek();
both updating same object in redux?

Comment: Yes, they are in different `switch-case` , i update my reducer file on my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your reducer you have added the fetched data into the main object in store, instead, you should have to maintain two different variables to save data of those different components separately. Try by changing the reducer as,

```
    import { 
      MOVIELIST_MAINACTIVITY,
      MOVIELIST_THISWEEK,
      MOVIELIST_THEATER
    } from '../actions/types';

    const INITIAL_STATE = {
      weeklyMovies:[],
      allMovies:[]
    };

    export default (state = INITIAL_STATE, action) => {
      switch (action.type) {   
        case MOVIELIST_MAINACTIVITY:
          return {
            ...state,
            allMovies:action.payload
         };

        case MOVIELIST_THISWEEK:
        return {
          ...state,
          weeklyMovies:action.payload
        };          

        case MOVIELIST_THEATER:
          console.log(action.payload);
          return action.payload;

        default:
          return {...state};
      }
    };
```

And in your component A and B you should change your mapStateToProps to read data from corresponding objects in store.

For MainActivity component

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  const movieList = state.allMovies;
  return { movieList };
};
```

and for ThisWeek component

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  const movieList = state.weeklyMovies;
  return { movieList };
};
```

Comment: Thanks @Rohith, i try your code i find i can get different `this.props` by different component now.  Can i ask you one more thing? In my `switch-case` MOVIELIST_THEATER. All my other theater list use the same class component and the reducer. How do i avoid the problem if i try your code ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to add one more object say, 'theatreList' in the reducer, save the value to it just like weeklyMovies and allMovies and access the value from this object in ur component

Comment: Thanks for your reply, it helps me a lot, Thank you !